# Doom Emacs linter disable?

Tags: doom, warning

[image: elisp linter warning]

I'm using Doom Emacs.  How can I disable these unhelpful warning messages?

Comment: I think this tip is at least valuable. If you really want to turn it off, try turning off `flycheck-mode`.

Comment: This particular tip is actually quite useless.  I'm *already* using (interactive) and changing `open-line` to `forward-line` breaks the function.  Turning off `flycheck-mode` doesn't help at all, the tip is still there.

Comment: I notice that the warning is against programmatic use of `next-line`, not `open-line`, even though point seems to be (is?) on `open-line`.  `next-line` is on (as it happens) the next line.  So that flycheck tip looks very strange to me.  The real question here may be why you are getting this apparently misaligned `flycheck` behavior.